# Angular 6 Observable Http get async

Tags: httpclient, angular6

i'm newbie at angular and i have problem with get async data from http client, my code:

User Service:

```
  getAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.API_URL}/users`);
  }

  registerUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.API_URL}/api/auth/registerUser`, user);
  }
```

User model:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  surname: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  street: string;
  numberStreet: string;
  postalCode: string;
  city: string;
}
```

User-list component:

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private modalService: NgbModal) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListUsers();
  }

  getListUsers() {
    this.userService.getAll().subscribe(
      restItems => {
        this.data = restItems;
      }
    );
  }

this.userService.registerUser(this.registerForm.value)
}
```

and now if i add user and send post in database user is stored, but on front it doesnt come up. After reload page list of users working

Comment: Can you please explain more about your question and provide more infomation

Comment: When i add user, there is no 'live update' at my datatable in component.html, like https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1 it this tutorial when i add new hero this hero appears in list heroes